# Styling rendered iframe in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title says, I'm trying to style an iframe from rendered content in React. I am needing to set the iframe's width and height to an aspect ratio, which typically requires wrapping the iframe in a specific div. Since it's being pulled in from post content data, I don't have the ability to add a wrapper div to the iframe. Is there a way to manage the width and height of an iframe for this type of scenario?

Also, not using jQuery, so that is not an option.

Comment: What about width and height properties for the iframe? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: I've tried setting the width and height both to 100%, the width works, but the height doesn't change, it ends up being about 100px

Comment: 100% of what? who is the "parent"? maybe show your code please...

Comment: I'm getting the post content from WordPress. So 1) there isn't a parent, to be user friendly, the post writer just inserts the iframe, there isn't a typical "parent", as i said it's rendered content. 2) with that, it's not really an option to add a class name as the post writer would have to know how to do that, and that is not user friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out actually.

I added this into the WP functions.php

```
function div_wrapper($content) {
    // match any iframes
    $pattern = '~<iframe.*</iframe>|<embed.*</embed>~';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        // wrap matched iframe with div
        $wrappedframe = '<div>' . $match . '</div>';

        //replace original iframe with new in content
        $content = str_replace($match, $wrappedframe, $content);
    }

    return $content;    
}
add_filter('the_content', 'div_wrapper');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do three things here,

1. set a className to your iframe and control by css/sass/less whatever you use
2. add the style class to your iframe tag style={{}}
3. add a ref to your iframe and manipulate the styles with js

i hope this works for you